# How to get the Response Header with Rest connector loopback 4?

Tags: loopback4

If the external api returns the required response in the response header instead of response body, how to get them?

lb4 service seems to return only response body rejecting the response header

Answer (score 0):

The header can be retrieved by setting the `operations[].template.fullResponse` connector configuration. This causes the  the full response object from [Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69880580/how-to-get-the-response-header-with-rest-connector-loopback-4).